# How to split a list by Regex

Tags: scala

I have a very large amount of list and I need to split by the last occurrence of a 3char sequence. EX(AE3,SH7,SH8). How would I split to make all the characters following it a separate list?

I've tried using SplitAt but it doesn't seem to work regex. Also LastIndexOf returns -1

```
val pattern = "[a-zA-Z]{2}\\d{1}".r     //This is my Regex
```

This is an example of the list I am dealing with
I need all the characters after EY1.

```
List(}CLOSE-BRACE, , K, L, OW1, Z, B, R, EY1, S) 
List(}RIGHT-BRACE, , R, AY1, T, B, R, EY1, S)
```

and I would want it to out output (EY1 ,S)

Would an array be better for this because I am converting all lines in the file to get a bunch of list like this

Comment: To be honest it is not really clear, what you are trying to achieve. Can you try to rephrase your question and add input and desired output?

Comment: It's an "ok" question, not sure why people are voting to close it. The OP is looking for a way to get all elements of a list after, and including, the last one matching a condition. Kinda `takeWhile(!..)`, except that looks for the first match not last.

Answer (score 1):

I think something like this should work ...

```
list.foldLeft(false -> Nil) { 
    case (_, elem) if elem.matches("[A-z]{2}\\d.") => true -> elem :: Nil
    case ((false, _), _) => false -> Nil
    case ((true, result), elem) => elem :: result
 } match { 
   case (true, result) => result.reverse
   case _ => Nil
 }
```